# Laravel get only models with current version

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have implemented custom model versioning in Laravel Framework. There is couple of columns handling it in the database table: `sibling_id` (links model's different versions together), `version`, `accepted` and `validFrom`.

For example:

```
| id | sibling_id | version | accepted | validFrom  | ... |
|----|------------|---------|----------|------------|-----|
| 1  | 1          | 1       | 1        | 2017-12-01 |     |
| 2  | 1          | 2       | 1        | 2018-06-01 |     |
| 3  | 2          | 1       | 1        | 2017-12-10 |     |
| 4  | 2          | 2       | 0        | 2017-12-28 |     |
| 5  | 3          | 1       | 0        | 2017-12-01 |     |
```

What I mean with current model:

- model having the biggest version number within accepted and valid modals
- **OR** version 1 if there isn't any other versions

I would like to have some way to get normally only current model grouped by `sibling_id` (so within this example the collection should include models 1, 3 and 5). This should work like same way than Laravel's `withTrashed()` function so that I can include all if I want to (for example version history).

Maybe this can be done somehow with the scopes but I felt it complicated because of the "sibling grouping" and another complex filters so I ended up to ask here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think a SQL View would be easier to work with, rather than build the query with Laravel.

I'd build a view implementing the query something along:

```
select t.* from table as t
    join (select sibling_id, MAX(version) as version from table group by sibling_id) as grouped 
       on grouped.sibling_id = t.sibling_id and t.version = grouped.version;
```

Then map another eloquent model for the view in Laravel. This way, you can just select from the table if you want to get all, or from the view if you want "unique" records.